# getting the filepath of a file input in php

Tags: php, file-upload, input, upload

How do I get the filepath of the a file that uploaded using the file input? My code is:

This is my file input

```
<input type="file"  id="filebut">
```

The textbox that I want my filepath to show

```
<input id="browsephoto" type="text" readonly>
```

I want it that when I select a file using my file input, I want it to show the text: "C:\fakepath\"filename.

How is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: You can't get the original path - the browser doesn't supply the information. Only the file name, the file itself and a couple of properties like size are available.

Answer (score 0):

Such info isn't transferred by browser thus not available.

Comment: @Qǝ uoɯᴉs: it's not. Do you have any real comment to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the full file path but you can get file name and 'fakepath':

`document.getElementById('my_input_id_goes_here').value`